# Adding external library as file in Android Studio causing dependency error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library

I tried to add [mXparser](https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser) library downloaded from [here](http://mathparser.org/).

I have downloaded zip file and extracted java part as the separate file. I've created `'libraries'` file under Project structure and pasted this library inside. Then I've added `include ':libraries:mXparser'` inside `settings.gradle` file.

After this step I clicked `File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> + -> Module dependency` and I added this library and clicked `"OK"`.

I'm getting these errors after compilation. How to fix them?

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve project :libraries:mXparser. Open File Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :libraries:mXparser. Open File Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :libraries:mXparser. Open File Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve project :libraries:mXparser. Open File Show Details
>
> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :libraries:mXparser. Open File Show Details

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding jar file wrongly.
Perform below steps to add `mXparser` library.

**1.** Download [this](https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser/releases/download/v.4.0.0/mxparser-v.4.0.0-bin-only.zip) file and extract and you will get a `jar` file.

**2.** Copy `jar` file from that folder where you downloaded, and Paste it in `libs` folder under app folder of your project.

**3.** Now paste `jar` file here in `libs` folder

**4.** Once your `JAR` file is successfully copied to libs folder and we will add them as dependency files.

**5.** Click on *File > Project Structure >Select app > Dependencies* Tab.

**6.** Click on **(+)** plus button given on right side and select `File Dependency`.

**7.** This will pop up a dialog box for selecting path. Under this open `libs` folder and add your Jar files one by one.

**8.** Once you select `Jar` file then click `Ok` button and your `Gradle` will Start building.

You can refer [here](https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/import-add-external-jar-files-android-studio.html) for the complete tutorial.